# How to jump to bottom of page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, scrollto

I need to jump to the bottom of page after button click. After clicking, some hiden information becomes visible and it expands the page. I tried this:

```
onclick='if(event.pageY > (document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight - 250)) {window.scrollBy(0, (document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight));}
```

**where:**

> *event.pageY* - mouse position on click
>
> *(document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight - 250)* - i need to do this
>   action just after clicking last few buttons (250px above bottom)

But this jumps only to the bottom of previous (not expanded) page with hidden lines. Then i need to scroll to see information that become visible. I need to jump to the bottom of expanded page with shown information that was hiden.

---

2nd problem that it works different in chrome and firefox. Chrome works only with bottom of whole page - 250px and firefox  works with visible part of page - 250px.

---

Any advice? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to scroll in an animated way or just jump to the bottom ?

Comment: You need to do the scrolling *after* the page has expanded, not before.